# Skyrim Special Edition launching issues

Tags: technical-issues, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[image]

I've learned how to download skse64 to get SkyrimSE working properly with my mods until I had some issues at Lakeview manner where my game would crash EVERY TIME I get near it.
So I uninstalled SkyrimSE to see if that would fix the problem.
To my misfortune, after reinstalling both SE and the skse64; when I try to launch my game from the "skse64_loader" this message pops up:

> REL/Relocation.h(617): failed to open.

If it's not one thing it's another with this game.
Can someone help and tell me what's going on and what to do?

Comment: Did you delete the installation folder after uninstalling SkyrimSE? There were probably some left over files.

Comment: No.
I just uninstalled and that was it.
I don't go into my files deleting folders after uninstalling a game

Comment: Normaly you don't need to, but when modding it is good practise to clean up after manually.

Comment: Okay so what do I do?

Comment: Reinstall everything again?

Comment: WOW! I reinstalled the game and I still get this message. I am lost!
Without this my SKYUI doesn't work and reads "error"